# JDBC authorization in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-security

I'm trying to set up simple authentication and authorization using JDBC (mysql). Here is the sql that im using to init users:

```
INSERT INTO users(username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('admin','admin', true);
INSERT INTO user_roles (username, role)
VALUES ('admin', 'USER');
INSERT INTO user_roles (username, role)
VALUES ('admin', 'ADMIN');
```

datasource properties:

```
spring.datasource.password=xxxx 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
spring.datasource.username=xxx
```

security config:

```
 class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource source;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/uploadfiles/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(source).
                usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username=?").
                authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

}
```

logging in works well but when trying to open /uploadfiles link as an admin i get 403 response. I also tried to check if roles are correct and they are. I checked them using this code:

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            authorities.forEach(authority -> logger.info(authority.toString()));
```

also when i set up inMemoryAuthentication it works as expected, so i guess it had to be something with mysql configuration. Anyone sees mistakes in my code ?

Comment: Does your `role` column contain authorities ('ADMIN') or roles ('ROLE_ADMIN')?

Comment: It's 'ADMIN', 'USER' etc. without any prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your authorities SQL query to:

```sql
select username, concat('ROLE_',role) from user_roles where username=?
```

*Roles are authorities prefixed with "ROLE_".*